# Can we define flat connection on any given smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

For example, a sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is apparently not flat with respect to the Euclidean connection, but can we define a flat connection and thus with affine charts on $S^2$?

Comment: @Peter Franek: Gauss-Bonet only considers the Riemannian connection but here I don't require such condition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are topological obstructions to a vector bundle admitting a flat connection: most simply, by [Chern-Weil theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism) the real Pontryagin classes of such a bundle must all vanish. So, for example, any closed $4$-manifold with nonzero signature, such as $\mathbb{CP}^2$, does not admit a flat connection.

Also by Chern-Weil theory, or by the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) (which is stated on Wikipedia for the Levi-Civita connection but in fact holds for any connection), if an oriented vector bundle admits a flat connection then the real Euler class must also vanish, meaning that the Euler characteristic must be zero. So it follows that $S^2$ also does not admit a flat connection.

Comment: Maybe this way will be true? Without the use of characteristic classes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807138/is-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-s2-flat