# Confusion on the intuition of a connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

At 6:27 of [this lecture](https://youtu.be/2eVWUdcI2ho?t=397) by Frederic Schuller, it is remarked that only when we fix the connection (by providing Christoffel's) that we get the specific shape of the sphere that we usually imagine, and, perhaps a choice of a different connection would have ended up in a sphere:

> [image]

This is all good and fine. But then I saw this video by [Eigen Chris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEEahoUUGyc&list=PLJHszsWbB6hpk5h8lSfBkVrpjsqvUGTCx&index=23), and [17:55](https://youtu.be/cEEahoUUGyc?t=1075) of it, he says that one can set all the Christoffels while on the sphere to zero to get another connection named the boring connection:

> [image]

Now this is contradictory with the Schuller lecture's to me because of two points:

1. In Schuller's lectures, it is found that the connection fixes the shape, but here Eigen Chris has concluded that a single shape can have more than one connection.
2. At [1hr 4mins of the 7th lecture](https://youtu.be/nEaiZBbCVtI?t=3895) of the GR course by Frederic Schuller, it is mentioned that it is impossible to have a connection with Gammas vanishing on each coordinate chart on a hyperbolic surface. I am supposing this would extend to the sphere case as well.

Picture:

> [image]

How do I resolve the apparent contradiction here?

Comment: A general suggestion: Learn math not by watching videos but by reading books.

Comment: I looked up both Frederic Schuller and Eigen Chris: Neither one is an expert in differential geometry.

Comment: There is no trivial connection on the tangent  bundle of the sphere.

Comment: Indeed, eigenchris has only an undergraduate background in physics and EE. Certainly an expert in differential geometry. *rolls uncountably many eyes*

Comment: Well I mean, there are a large number of people who are learning DG from his lecture, so if there is a mistake and it's correction can be said here, then that'll be helpful to a lot of folks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we can say

- A given smooth manifold $M$ can have many possible connections.
- If a manifold $M$ can be covered by a single coordinate chart, then you can transport the trivial connection of $\Bbb{R}^n$ onto the manifold $M$. In other words, using that single chart, we can set all the $\Gamma=0$, and thus we have a trivial/flat connection on $M$. However, the sphere cannot be covered by a single chart ($S^2$ is compact), and also $S^2$ [does not admit a flat connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807138/1062628).

I briefly watched the lectrue, and it seems the point he's trying to make is that the unit sphere $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3\,:\,x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ and the the ellipse $E=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3\,:\, (x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2=1\}$ (with $a,b,c>0$ and not all equal to $1$) are diffeomorphic manifolds and in that sense we can't 'tell them apart'. However, from an extrinsic point of view, once you consider their embedding in $\Bbb{R}^3$, they are clearly different sets. We might then ask what intrinsically makes them 'different'. One approach is to consider their induced metric $g_S$ and $g_E$; then they are not isometric as Riemannian manifolds.

Also, you seem to be using the word 'shape' in more than one sense hence your confusion.

Comment: Could you explain more specifically how you think I am abusing the word shape?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos You say '*In Schuller's lectures, it is found that the connection fixes the shape, but here Eigen Chris has concluded that a single shape can have more than one connection.*' The first use is talking about shapes as in sphere vs ellipse. The second use is more like you mean a surface/manifold instead of shape. WHat you mean is "EigenCrhis has concluded that a single **manifold** can have more than one connection" (though as I, and others have said, Eigen Chris' remark about the 'boring connection' on $S^2$ is wrong! This doesn't exist for $S^2$).

Comment: Then what on earth was he calculating there ? O_O

Comment: @Aplateofmomos like others have said (though I wouldn't phrase it that extremely), watch videos, but you should always consult a proper differential geometry/Riemannian geometry text after. For example, John Lee's Riemannian geometry book is very nice.

Comment: Well yes, that's well and good I registered that before itself.. but I am trying to understand the thing I said before still

Comment: @Aplateofmomos there is no flat connection on $S^2$. So I'm not sure what else I can say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136692/discussion-between-spicy-potatoes-and-a-plate-of-momos).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what others have said - you can set the Christoffel symbols to zero *in one coordinate patch* and get a *local* connection in that patch. But for $S^2$, you wouldn't be able to set them to zero in all coordinate patches covering $S^2$ simultaneously - one can show that in going from a coordinates $x^i$ to $\bar{x}^i$, the Christoffel symbols must transform like
$$
\bar{\Gamma}^i_{\ jk} = \frac{\partial\bar{x}^i}{\partial x_m}\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial \bar{x}^j}\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial \bar{x}^k}\Gamma^m_{\ np} + \frac{\partial^2x^m}{\partial\bar{x}^j\partial\bar{x}^k}\frac{\partial\bar{x}^i}{\partial x^m}
$$
in order to define a consistent *global* connection. For the sphere, $\bar\Gamma^i_{\ jk}$ and $\Gamma^m_{\ np}$ can't both be zero, since the last term doesn't vanish no matter what two coordinate patches you choose to cover $S^2$ (assuming a minimal cover of two patches here). So Eigen Chris' video is somewhat misleading in that respect.